# Counter-example to $\text{im}(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq \text{im}(T_1) + \text{im}(T_2)$ and $\ker(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq\text{im}(T_1) \cap \text{im}(T_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformations from $U$ to $V$.

The counter-examples that I found to 
$$\text{im}(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq\text{im}(T_1) + \text{im}(T_2) \tag{1}$$ 
is : 
Suppose $B=\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $R^2$. $T_1: R^2\to R^2$ is defined by $T_1(av_1+bv_2)=a$; $T_2: R^2->R^2$ is defined by $T_2(av_1+bv_2)=-a$. Then $ker(T_1)=[0, m]$, $ker(T_2)=[0, m]$ but $ker(T_1 + T_2)=[n, m]$ for $m,n \in R$

The counter-examples that I found to 
$$\ker(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq \text{ker}(T_1) \cap \text{ker}(T_2)\tag 2$$ 
is : 
Let $A=$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, $B=$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$T_1: R^2\to R^2$ is defined by $T_1(v)=Av$; $T_2: R^2->R^2$ is defined by $T_2(v)=Bv$. Then $ker(T_1)=[0, 0]$, $ker(T_2)=[0, 0]$ but $ker(T_1 + T_2)=[n, m]$ for $m,n \in R$

Are these examples correct? Can you give an example to (1) which is irrelevant to the chosen of basis?

Comment: what counter examples did you find?

Comment: There is no counter-example for (1). For (2) try an example with $T_2=-T_1$.

Comment: (2) does not make sense, since the left hand side is a subspace of $U$ while the right hand side is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, there is a typo to the former edition which has been modified just now.